# Implementation of the Hindley-Milner type system (with evaluation, without type inference) as a library for use in compilers

Tags: haskell, compiler

I've written an implementation of the [Hindley-Milner type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system) as a "Core" language for use in writing compilers of typed functional languages. This is meant to be used as a library by compilers of more complex languages, providing an in-memory intermediate representation after parsing, type inference, and typechecking in more elaborate systems.

Goals:

- Provide a correct type system with literal Int and Bool types, as well as if-then-else expressions.
- Allow evaluation of well-typed expressions in the language.

Deliberate non-goals:

- Provide type inference.
- Allow Haskell-style typeclasses.
- Provide parsing from text.
- Provide end-to-end typing and evaluation.

The code is currently separated into three modules, as well as one module for testing. I'm primarily looking for general stylistic critique, as well as making sure the typechecking algorithm is correct. One other specific issue I'd like feedback on is how to handle partial functions in the `Eval` module; they're intentionally partial, as only ill-typed expressions shouldn't evaluate successfully, but I'm not sure how best to handle this and what sort of API to provide.

Syntax.hs:

```
module Syntax where

type Identifier = String

data Literal = LInt Integer
             | LBool Bool
             deriving (Show, Eq)

--division deliberately omitted to avoid dealing with integer division complexity
data BinOp = Add
           | Subtract
           | Multiply
           | Equals
           deriving (Show, Eq)

data CoreExpr = Var Identifier
              | Lit Literal
              | Apply CoreExpr CoreExpr --function, then argument
              | Lambda Identifier Type CoreExpr --name of argument, type of argument, then body
              | Let Identifier CoreExpr CoreExpr --let a b e is equivalent to let a = b in e
              | If CoreExpr CoreExpr CoreExpr --if cond a b is equivalent to if cond then a else b
              | Op BinOp CoreExpr CoreExpr
              | Fix CoreExpr
              deriving (Show, Eq)

type Decl = (String, CoreExpr) -- top-level let declaration

data Program = Program [Decl] CoreExpr -- last CoreExpr is the main function

type TypeVariable = String

data Type = TVariable TypeVariable
          | TConstructor String
          | TFunction Type Type
          deriving (Show, Eq)

tInt, tBool :: Type
tInt = TConstructor "Int"
tBool = TConstructor "Bool"
```

Type.hs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

module Type (
    TypeError(..)
  , typeOf
) where

-- need the MTL versions of these libraries for auto-lifting
import Control.Monad.Except
import Control.Monad.Reader
import qualified Data.Map as Map

import Syntax

data TypeError = Mismatch Type Type
               | NotFunction Type -- attempting to apply a non-function to an argument, or fix a non-function
               | NotInScope Identifier
               deriving (Show, Eq)

type TypingEnv = Map.Map Identifier Type

type TypingSubstitution = Map.Map TypeVariable Type

-- monad stack to store typing environment, typing errors
type Check a = ExceptT TypeError (Reader (TypingEnv, TypingSubstitution)) a

extendEnv :: Identifier -> Type -> TypingEnv -> TypingEnv
extendEnv = Map.insert

extendSub :: TypeVariable -> Type -> TypingSubstitution -> TypingSubstitution
extendSub = Map.insert

-- add name: typ to the environment, then run a typecheck
checkInEnv :: Identifier -> Type -> Check a -> Check a
checkInEnv name typ = local $ \(env, sub) -> (extendEnv name typ env, sub)

lookupVar :: Identifier -> Check Type
lookupVar name = do
    (env, _) <- ask
    case Map.lookup name env of
        Just t -> return t
        Nothing -> throwError $ NotInScope name

typeCheck :: CoreExpr -> Check Type
typeCheck = \case
    Lit (LInt _) -> return tInt

    Lit (LBool _) -> return tBool

    Var name -> lookupVar name

    Lambda name typ body -> do
        rhs <- checkInEnv name typ (typeCheck body)
        return $ TFunction typ rhs

    Apply func arg -> do
        funcType <- typeCheck func
        argType <- typeCheck arg
        (_, subst) <- ask

        case funcType of
            TFunction a b -> case a of
                TVariable tvar -> return $ applySubstitution (extendSub tvar argType subst) b
                -- TConstructor, TFunction
                _ -> if a == argType
                        then return b
                        else throwError $ Mismatch argType a
            nonFunc -> throwError $ NotFunction nonFunc

    Let name value body -> do
        valueType <- typeCheck value
        checkInEnv name valueType (typeCheck body)

    If cond tr fl -> do
        condType <- typeCheck cond
        trueType <- typeCheck tr
        falseType <- typeCheck fl
        if condType /= tBool
            then throwError $ Mismatch condType tBool
            else if trueType /= falseType
                then throwError $ Mismatch trueType falseType
                else return trueType

    Op op left right -> do
        leftType <- typeCheck left
        rightType <- typeCheck right
        case op of
            -- only define equality on ints
            Equals -> if leftType == tInt 
                        then if rightType == tInt
                                then return tBool
                                else throwError $ Mismatch tInt rightType
                        else throwError $ Mismatch leftType tInt
            -- Add, Subtract, Multiply
            _ -> if leftType == tInt 
                    then if rightType == tInt
                        then return tInt
                        else throwError $ Mismatch tInt rightType
                    else throwError $ Mismatch leftType tInt

    Fix expr -> do
        innerType <- typeCheck expr
        case innerType of
                    TFunction a b | a == b -> return a
                                  | otherwise -> throwError $ Mismatch a b
                    nonFunc -> throwError $ NotFunction nonFunc

-- make this a typeclass method later, when it can be applied to other type-containing structures?
applySubstitution :: TypingSubstitution -> Type -> Type
applySubstitution subst typ = case typ of
    TVariable tvar -> case Map.lookup tvar subst of
        Just typ' -> typ'
        Nothing -> typ
    TConstructor _ -> typ
    TFunction tArg tBody -> TFunction (applySubstitution subst tArg) (applySubstitution subst tBody)

runTypecheck :: (TypingEnv, TypingSubstitution) -> Check a -> Either TypeError a
runTypecheck (env, sub) checker = runReader (runExceptT checker) (env, sub)

typeOf :: CoreExpr -> Either TypeError Type
typeOf expr = runTypecheck (Map.empty, Map.empty) (typeCheck expr)
```

Eval.hs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

module Eval (
    eval
  , evalProgram
  , Value(..)
) where

import Syntax

import qualified Data.Map as Map

type Environment = Map.Map String Value

data Value = VInt Integer
           | VBool Bool
           | VClosure String CoreExpr Environment
           deriving Eq

instance Show Value where
    show (VInt n) = show n
    show (VBool b) = show b
    show (VClosure{}) = "<closure>"

eval :: Environment -> CoreExpr -> Value
eval env = \case
    Lit (LInt n) -> VInt n
    Lit (LBool b) -> VBool b
    Var name -> case Map.lookup name env of
        (Just val) -> val
        Nothing -> error $ "Variable " ++ show name ++ " not in scope"

    -- ignore type; we presume it's already been typechecked
    Lambda name _ body -> VClosure name body env
    Apply func arg -> apply (eval env func) (eval env arg)
    Let name value body -> eval env' body
        where env' = Map.insert name (eval env value) env
    If cond tr fl -> case eval env cond of
        VBool check -> if check then eval env tr else eval env fl
        _ -> error "Non-boolean used as condition"
    Op op left right -> case op of
        Add -> VInt $ m + n
        Subtract -> VInt $ m - n
        Multiply -> VInt $ m * n
        Equals -> VBool $ m == n
        where (VInt m) = eval env left --accept that these are partial for now,
              (VInt n) = eval env right --will eliminate possibility of error with typechecker later
    Fix expr -> eval env (Apply expr (Fix expr))

--beta reduction: replace a bound variable in the lambda with the argument to the lambda
apply :: Value -> Value -> Value
apply (VClosure name body env) arg = eval (Map.insert name arg env) body
apply _ _ = error "Tried to apply a non-closure"

evalProgram :: Program -> Value
evalProgram (Program decls main) = eval populatedEnv main
    where populatedEnv = foldr addDecl Map.empty decls
          addDecl (ident, expr) env = Map.insert ident (eval env expr) env
```

Test.hs:

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Hedgehog ((===))
import qualified Hedgehog as HH
import qualified Hedgehog.Gen as Gen
import qualified Hedgehog.Range as Range
import Test.Tasty
import Test.Tasty.ExpectedFailure
import Test.Tasty.Hedgehog
import Test.Tasty.HUnit

import Eval
import Syntax
import Type

main = defaultMain tests

tests :: TestTree
tests = testGroup "All Tests" [properties, units]

-- property-based testing

properties :: TestTree
properties = testGroup "Properties" [ combinators, evaluation, typechecking ]

combinators :: TestTree
combinators = testGroup "Lambda calculus combinators" [identity, kConst, skki]

evaluation :: TestTree
evaluation = testGroup "Basic evaluation" [ifTrue, ifFalse, addOp, subOp, mulOp, eqOp]

typechecking :: TestTree
typechecking = testGroup "Type checking" [ intType
                                         , boolType
                                         , appliedFuncType
                                         , arithOpType
                                         , mismatchedArithOpLeft 
                                         , mismatchedArithOpRight
                                         ]

identity = testProperty "I combinator is identity" propIdentity
kConst = testProperty "K combinator is const" propKConst
skki = testProperty "SKK == I" propSKKI
ifTrue = testProperty "if true a b == a" propIfTrue
ifFalse = testProperty "if false a b == b" propIfFalse
addOp = testProperty "Add a b == a + b" propAddOp
subOp = testProperty "Subtract a b == a - b" propSubOp
mulOp = testProperty "Multiply a b == a * b" propMulOp
eqOp = testProperty "Equals a b == (a == b)" propEqOp
intType = testProperty "typeof (any integer) == tInt" propIntType
boolType = testProperty "typeof (any boolean) == tBool" propBoolType
appliedFuncType = testProperty "typeof (\\x : Int -> x) (any integer) == tInt" propAppliedFunc
arithOpType = testProperty "typeof (any Add/Subtract/Multiply) (any int) (any int) == tInt" propArithOp
mismatchedArithOpLeft = testProperty "typeof (Add/Subtract/Multiply) (any bool) (any int) == Mismatch tBool tInt" propArithMismatchLeft
mismatchedArithOpRight = testProperty "typeof (Add/Subtract/Multiply) (any int) (any bool) == Mismatch tInt tBool" propArithMismatchRight

-- generators

genAnyInt :: HH.Gen Integer
genAnyInt = Gen.integral (Range.linear (-10000) 10000)

genArithOp :: HH.Gen BinOp
genArithOp = Gen.element [Add, Subtract, Multiply]

-- lambda calculus combinators
iComb :: CoreExpr
iComb = Lambda "x" (TVariable "a") (Var "x")

kComb :: CoreExpr
kComb = Lambda "x" (TVariable "a") (Lambda "y" (TVariable "b") (Var "x"))

sComb :: CoreExpr
sComb = Lambda "f" (TFunction (TVariable "a") (TFunction (TVariable "b") (TVariable "c"))) (Lambda "g" (TFunction (TVariable "a") (TVariable "b")) (Lambda "x" (TVariable "a") (Apply (Apply (Var "f") (Var "x")) (Apply (Var "g") (Var "x")))))

-- tests

propIdentity :: HH.Property
propIdentity = HH.property $ do
    n <- HH.forAll genAnyInt
    let ln = Lit . LInt $ n
    let vn = VInt n
    eval (Map.empty) (Apply iComb ln) === vn

propKConst :: HH.Property
propKConst = HH.property $ do
    m <- HH.forAll genAnyInt
    let lm = Lit . LInt $ m
    let vm = VInt m
    n <- HH.forAll genAnyInt
    let ln = Lit . LInt $ n
    eval (Map.empty) (Apply (Apply kComb lm) ln) === vm

propSKKI :: HH.Property
propSKKI = HH.property $ do
    n <- HH.forAll genAnyInt
    let ln = Lit . LInt $ n
    let vn = VInt n
    eval (Map.empty) (Apply (Apply (Apply sComb kComb) kComb) ln) === vn

propIfTrue :: HH.Property
propIfTrue = HH.property $ do
    m <- HH.forAll genAnyInt
    let lm = Lit . LInt $ m
    let vm = VInt m
    n <- HH.forAll genAnyInt
    let ln = Lit . LInt $ n
    eval Map.empty (If (Lit (LBool True)) lm ln) === vm

propIfFalse :: HH.Property
propIfFalse = HH.property $ do
    m <- HH.forAll genAnyInt
    let lm = Lit . LInt $ m
    n <- HH.forAll genAnyInt
    let ln = Lit . LInt $ n
    let vn = VInt n
    eval Map.empty (If (Lit (LBool False)) lm ln) === vn

propAddOp :: HH.Property
propAddOp = HH.property $ do
    m <- HH.forAll genAnyInt
    let lm = Lit . LInt $ m
    n <- HH.forAll genAnyInt
    let ln = Lit . LInt $ n
    eval Map.empty (Op Add lm ln) === VInt (m + n)

propSubOp :: HH.Property
propSubOp = HH.property $ do
    m <- HH.forAll genAnyInt
    let lm = Lit . LInt $ m
    n <- HH.forAll genAnyInt
    let ln = Lit . LInt $ n
    eval Map.empty (Op Subtract lm ln) === VInt (m - n)

propMulOp :: HH.Property
propMulOp = HH.property $ do
    m <- HH.forAll genAnyInt
    let lm = Lit . LInt $ m
    n <- HH.forAll genAnyInt
    let ln = Lit . LInt $ n
    eval Map.empty (Op Multiply lm ln) === VInt (m * n)

propEqOp :: HH.Property
propEqOp = HH.property $ do
    m <- HH.forAll genAnyInt
    let lm = Lit . LInt $ m
    n <- HH.forAll genAnyInt
    let ln = Lit . LInt $ n
    eval Map.empty (Op Equals lm ln) === VBool (m == n)

propIntType :: HH.Property
propIntType = HH.property $ do
    n <- HH.forAll genAnyInt
    let ln = Lit . LInt $ n
    typeOf ln === Right tInt

propBoolType :: HH.Property
propBoolType = HH.property $ do
    b <- HH.forAll Gen.bool
    let lb = Lit . LBool $ b
    typeOf lb === Right tBool

propAppliedFunc :: HH.Property
propAppliedFunc = HH.property $ do
    n <- HH.forAll genAnyInt
    let ln = Lit . LInt $ n
    typeOf (Apply (Lambda "x" tInt (Var "x")) ln) === Right tInt

propArithOp :: HH.Property
propArithOp = HH.property $ do
    op <- HH.forAll genArithOp
    m <- HH.forAll genAnyInt
    let lm = Lit . LInt $ m
    n <- HH.forAll genAnyInt
    let ln = Lit . LInt $ n
    typeOf (Op op lm ln) === Right tInt

propArithMismatchLeft :: HH.Property
propArithMismatchLeft = HH.property $ do
    op <- HH.forAll genArithOp
    b <- HH.forAll Gen.bool
    let lb = Lit . LBool $ b
    n <- HH.forAll genAnyInt
    let ln = Lit . LInt $ n
    typeOf (Op op lb ln) === Left (Mismatch tBool tInt)

propArithMismatchRight :: HH.Property
propArithMismatchRight = HH.property $ do
    op <- HH.forAll genArithOp
    n <- HH.forAll genAnyInt
    let ln = Lit . LInt $ n
    b <- HH.forAll Gen.bool
    let lb = Lit . LBool $ b
    typeOf (Op op ln lb) === Left (Mismatch tInt tBool)


-- unit testing

units :: TestTree
units = testGroup "Unit Tests" [letExample, fixExample, typeTests, programExample]

letExample :: TestTree
letExample = testCase "let x = 3 in x evaluates to 3" $ do
    let letExpression = Let "x" (Lit (LInt 3)) (Var "x")
    eval Map.empty letExpression @?= VInt 3

fixExample :: TestTree
fixExample = testCase "factorial 3 == 6" $ do
    let factorial = Fix (Lambda "fact" (TFunction tInt tInt) (Lambda "x" tInt (If (Op Equals (Var "x") (Lit (LInt 0))) (Lit (LInt 1)) (Op Multiply (Var "x") (Apply (Var "fact") (Op Subtract (Var "x") (Lit (LInt 1))))))))
    eval Map.empty (Apply factorial (Lit (LInt 3))) @?= VInt 6

typeTests :: TestTree
typeTests = testGroup "Unit tests of typechecker" [ funcAndVar
                                                  , outOfScope
                                                  , appliedToWrongType
                                                  , applyNonFunction
                                                  , nonBoolIfCondition
                                                  , mismatchedThenElse
                                                  , mismatchedEqualsLeft
                                                  , mismatchedEqualsRight
                                                  , correctIfElse
                                                  , correctEquals
                                                  , correctFix
                                                  , fixMismatch
                                                  , fixNonFunction
                                                  , correctApply
                                                  , correctLet
                                                  , letScopeCheck
                                                  , letInnerError
                                                  , letOuterError
                                                  , polymorphicLambda
                                                  , polymorphicLambdaMulti
                                                  , polymorphicApplied
                                                  , polymorphicAppliedMulti
                                                  , polymorphicPartialApplied
                                                  ]

funcAndVar :: TestTree
funcAndVar = testCase "typeof (\\x : Int -> x) = TFunction tInt tInt" $ do
    let lambdaExpr = Lambda "x" tInt (Var "x")
    typeOf lambdaExpr @?= Right (TFunction tInt tInt)

outOfScope :: TestTree
outOfScope = testCase "typeof x == NotInScope" $ do
    typeOf (Var "x") @?= Left (NotInScope "x")

appliedToWrongType :: TestTree
appliedToWrongType = testCase "typeof (\\x : Int -> x) True == Mismatch tBool tInt" $ do
    let lambdaExpr = Lambda "x" tInt (Var "x")
    typeOf (Apply lambdaExpr (Lit (LBool True))) @?= Left (Mismatch tBool tInt)

applyNonFunction :: TestTree
applyNonFunction = testCase "typeof (1 1) == NotFunction tInt" $ do
    typeOf (Apply (Lit (LInt 1)) (Lit (LInt 1))) @?= Left (NotFunction tInt)

nonBoolIfCondition :: TestTree
nonBoolIfCondition = testCase "typeof (if 1 then True else False) == Mismatch tInt tBool" $ do
    let ifExpr = If (Lit (LInt 1)) (Lit (LBool True)) (Lit (LBool False))
    typeOf ifExpr @?= Left (Mismatch tInt tBool)

mismatchedThenElse :: TestTree
mismatchedThenElse = testCase "typeof (if True then 1 else False) == Mismatch tInt tBool" $ do
    let ifExpr = If (Lit (LBool True)) (Lit (LInt 1)) (Lit (LBool False))
    typeOf ifExpr @?= Left (Mismatch tInt tBool)

mismatchedEqualsLeft :: TestTree
mismatchedEqualsLeft = testCase "typeof (True == 1) == Mismatch tBool tInt" $ do
    let eqExpr = Op Equals (Lit (LBool True)) (Lit (LInt 1)) 
    typeOf eqExpr @?= Left (Mismatch tBool tInt)

mismatchedEqualsRight :: TestTree
mismatchedEqualsRight = testCase "typeof (1 == True) == Mismatch tInt tBool" $ do
    let eqExpr = Op Equals (Lit (LInt 1)) (Lit (LBool True))
    typeOf eqExpr @?= Left (Mismatch tInt tBool)

correctIfElse :: TestTree
correctIfElse = testCase "typeof (if True then 1 else 2) == tInt" $ do
    let ifExpr = If (Lit (LBool True)) (Lit (LInt 1)) (Lit (LInt 2))
    typeOf ifExpr @?= Right tInt

correctEquals :: TestTree
correctEquals = testCase "typeof (1 == 2) == tBool" $ do
    let eqExpr = Op Equals (Lit (LInt 1)) (Lit (LInt 2))
    typeOf eqExpr @?= Right tBool

correctFix :: TestTree
correctFix = testCase "typeof Fix factorial == TFunction tInt tInt" $ do
    let factorial = Fix (Lambda "fact" (TFunction tInt tInt) (Lambda "x" tInt (If (Op Equals (Var "x") (Lit (LInt 0))) (Lit (LInt 1)) (Op Multiply (Var "x") (Apply (Var "fact") (Op Subtract (Var "x") (Lit (LInt 1))))))))
    typeOf factorial @?= Right (TFunction tInt tInt)

fixMismatch :: TestTree
fixMismatch = testCase "typeof Fix (\\x : Bool -> 1) == Mismatch tBool tInt" $ do
    let badFunc = Fix (Lambda "x" tBool (Lit (LInt 1)))
    typeOf badFunc @?= Left (Mismatch tBool tInt)

fixNonFunction :: TestTree
fixNonFunction = testCase "typeof Fix 1 == NotFunction tInt" $ do
    typeOf (Fix (Lit (LInt 1))) @?= Left (NotFunction tInt)

correctApply :: TestTree
correctApply = testCase "typeof ((\\x : Int -> x)1) == tInt" $ do
    let applyExpr = Apply (Lambda "x" tInt (Var "x")) (Lit (LInt 1))
    typeOf applyExpr @?= Right tInt

correctLet :: TestTree
correctLet = testCase "typeof (let x = 1 in True) == tBool" $ do
    let letExpr = Let "x" (Lit (LInt 1)) (Lit (LBool True))
    typeOf letExpr @?= Right tBool

-- make sure that the "let x = a" part of let...in is in scope when checking "in b"
letScopeCheck :: TestTree
letScopeCheck = testCase "typeof (let x = 1 in x) == tInt" $ do
    let letExpr = Let "x" (Lit (LInt 1)) (Var "x")
    typeOf letExpr @?= Right tInt

-- error in the "let x = a" part of let...in
letInnerError :: TestTree
letInnerError = testCase "typeof (let x = ((\\n : Int -> 1)True) in True) == Mismatch tBool tInt" $ do
    let letExpr = Let "x" (Apply (Lambda "n" tInt (Lit (LInt 1))) (Lit (LBool True))) (Lit (LBool True))
    typeOf letExpr @?= Left (Mismatch tBool tInt)

-- error in the "in b" part of let...in
letOuterError :: TestTree
letOuterError = testCase "typeof (let x = 1 in y) == NotInScope" $ do
    let letExpr = Let "x" (Lit (LInt 1)) (Var "y")
    typeOf letExpr @?= Left (NotInScope "y")

-- convert to property test?
polymorphicLambda :: TestTree
polymorphicLambda = testCase "typeof (\\x : a -> x) == TFunction (TVariable\"a\") (TVariable \"a\")" $ do
    let idExpr = Lambda "x" (TVariable "a") (Var "x")
    typeOf idExpr @?= Right (TFunction (TVariable "a") (TVariable "a"))

-- convert to property test?
polymorphicLambdaMulti :: TestTree
polymorphicLambdaMulti = testCase "typeof (\\x : a -> (\\y : b -> x)) == TFunction (TVariable \"a\" (TFunction (TVariable \"b\") (TVariable \"a\"))" $ do
    let constExpr = Lambda "x" (TVariable "a") (Lambda "y" (TVariable "b") (Var "x"))
    typeOf constExpr @?= Right (TFunction (TVariable "a") (TFunction (TVariable "b") (TVariable "a")))

-- convert to property test?
polymorphicApplied :: TestTree
polymorphicApplied = testCase "typeof ((\\x : a -> x)True) == tBool" $ do
    let idExpr = Lambda "x" (TVariable "a") (Var "x")
    typeOf (Apply idExpr (Lit (LBool True))) @?= Right tBool

-- convert to property test?
polymorphicAppliedMulti :: TestTree
polymorphicAppliedMulti = testCase "typeof (((\\x : a -> (\\y : b -> x))3)True) == tInt" $ do
    let constExpr = Lambda "x" (TVariable "a") (Lambda "y" (TVariable "b") (Var "x"))
    typeOf (Apply (Apply constExpr (Lit (LInt 3))) (Lit (LBool True))) @?= Right tInt

-- convert to property test?
polymorphicPartialApplied :: TestTree
polymorphicPartialApplied = testCase "typeof ((\\x : a -> (\\y : b -> x))3) == TFunction (TVariable\"b\") tInt" $ do
    let constExpr = Lambda "x" (TVariable "a") (Lambda "y" (TVariable "b") (Var "x"))
    typeOf (Apply constExpr (Lit (LInt 3))) @?= Right (TFunction (TVariable "b") tInt)

programExample :: TestTree
programExample = testCase "evalProgram (program to calculate 1 + 2) == 3" $ do
    let mDecl = ("m", Lit (LInt 1))
    let nDecl = ("n", Lit (LInt 2))
    let mainExpr = Op Add (Var "m") (Var "n")
    evalProgram (Program [mDecl, nDecl] mainExpr) @?= VInt 3
```

The full repository is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/DylanSp/core1/tree/ecaace0b8054eb1eaf8fce005be9740c4d2b2b77); the code above is from commit `ecaace0b8054eb1eaf8fce005be9740c4d2b2b77`.